# How to create mock Json API for testing android application?

Tags: android, json, testing, mocking

I'm an android developer and I need to test my application that loads data from a JSON API but the backend is not ready yet, but I have the JSON response that I'll be using, Is there any way I can create a mock api and can also perform some changes is the JSON objects, Also I want to test this on my phone so I don't know how local server will help.

Comment: are you using kotlin or java what are you for json response retrofit or volley

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10091980-testing-rest-apis-using-mockwebserver